# NavigationController, wait for user input until load first view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

i have a Navigationcontroller with multiple Views. The Cycle of my App should be:

1. App starts the first time and an UIAlertView is poping up.
2. If User clicks on the Button on the AlertView the NavigationController should load the first View.

But i don´t know how to implement everything that the NavController waits for the AlertView...Everything works fine now, except my first View has been loaded before the User does anything...

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this..First alertview will come. when you click ok then it will load the firstviewcontroller.

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Load the view" message:Nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
  [alert show];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
  }
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

  NSLog(@"%d",buttonIndex);

  if (buttonIndex == 0) {

  ```
  self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

  navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

  self.window.rootViewController = navController;
  ```

  }
  }

Comment: This could work. but i fire my AlertView not in didFinishLaunching...I fire it in another class...

Answer (score 0):

Create a "gatekeeper" like view, that is the root view controller of your navigation controller, this is an empty view that will present the alert view, then depending on that users selection, this view will either push the first or second view.

what are you trying to accomplish ? there might be better ways to do this depending on your problem, but this is the simplest solution that comes to mind ATM.

Comment: I already tried it that way...But i wasn´t able to Push the first View after User clicked

Comment: i tried it exactly the Way u described! But my AlertView will not be launched from that "gatekeeper" View...It will be launched from another class which is not a View...Therefor i don´t know the time when the user has clicked...

Comment: Well that's another problem then, and i meant showing us code snippets, but your problem is you weren't presenting the alertView Properly from the gatekeeper, do it in the gatekeeper's `viewDidAppear` method, then set the alertView's delegate to the gatekeeper `self` in that case., then all button clicks will be available to that view.